# How to convert .bin file to human readable strings?

Tags: c, encryption, hash, hex

I have a few .bin files that should contain a table of several hash values (CRC32, MD5, SHA1 and SHA256). I tried to convert the contents of a file to hex but the content does not make sense to me.

Original content (crc32_step.bin):

```
ÿÿÿÿÚ4Ã²ª½ÞUžÿ¼²AÙm¨Q¤7{1¦O²°Rsôj©¯½B«Ò#­ q‡‚\WöAÉÓÑDtG?jI¸×fÿ! YrŽ)¡K½¨œç|Y{€d!ÈÍÞõò¶ì—LD‹P´Æy®º6ÍÆèµQèÎß6{¶ÐÞ0;3¿æÜú³÷z|u0<²½]hÿ\:lœBé–0Ùž‚cÂÉD²š“×, ”[Cn,5òÖó,7ÖÌxú3qÆ!ÁGOŠép¿u0S«ž½wŠ¾­÷ÎÑ¤0£Êßâ~!2!Üt—êÓl³Ìaí”ÊÇ·ÅGjù"*IÝc>ud[ÄÏÏBŒ{‰ƒªs–£ƒÇ•âÈ0ä Ó<¶ûoeŠÕáé‚–ïs÷ÃÆ—‘®ä11‡¾
V>Û -iî#†Æ>–†“¹-?„žÂ¹4á0Lb+ð³¿uáj¾7€ü¨ÃëVîì´m½ÀýU_§¹Ð¦‡!@T
ˆíYFj=qŠþ ¯Î£WÁMýQ3Â²rÃî‚–D~$!4Ð™AK´É¡´*­¼žJ[¤ÆMÀý¶Á¤ß)õíèA³Åìä+(l€õè+Æ4ù2Û&Ð¢„ÑU¸ý(ÿ±t_)!çsâ'z‹ü‚üð˜‰Ë!ÉõcT%íå&}X‰Áã¹'Áê)7ÁM”$&í"Y K{Êã
³x~3H2%ò3VC<ß¬y«†„Dl-LåM·c¹Ñ¬A:@ÑËÀ6Å
```

Convert to Hex:

```
c3 bf c3 bf c3 bf c3 bf 1a c3 9a 34 c3 83 c2 b2 c2 aa c2 bd c3 9e 55 1c c5 be c3 bf c2 bc 1f c2 b2 41 c3 99 6d c2 a8 51 c2 a4 37 7b 07 31 c2 a6 4f c2 b2 c2 b0 0c 52 73 c3 b4 6a c2 a9 1a c2 af c2 bd 42 c2 ab c3 92 23 c2 ad 0e 20 71 e2 80 a1 e2 80 9a 5c 57 1c c3 b6 41 c3 89 c3 93 c3 91 c2 8f 44 74 47 3f 6a 49 c2 b8 c3 97 66 c3 bf 21 20 03 59 72 c5 bd 29 c2 a1 4b c2 bd c2 a8 0b c5 93 c3 a7 7c 59 7b e2 82 ac 64 21 c3 88 c3 8d c3 9e c3 b5 c3 b2 c2 90 c2 b6 04 c3 ac e2 80 94 4c 44 e2 80 b9 0e 50 c2 b4 c3 86 79 16 12 c2 ae c2 ba 36 c3 8d c3 86 c3 a8 c2 b5 1c 51 c3 a8 0c c3 8e c3 9f 36 7b c2 b6 c3 90 c3 9e 30 3b 33 c2 bf c3 a6 c3 9c c3 ba c2 b3 c3 b7 7a 7c 75 30 3c c2 b2 c2 bd 5d 68 13 c3 bf 5c 3a 6c c5 93 42 c3 a9 e2 80 93 30 c3 99 c5 be e2 80 9a 63 c3 82 c3 89 44 c2 b2 c5 a1 06 e2 80 9c c3 97 1b 2c 20 e2 80 9d 13 5b 0e 43 6e 2c 35 15 c3 b2 c3 96 c3 b3 2c 37 c3 96 c3 8c 78 c3 ba 33 71 c3 86 21 c3 81 47 0f 4f c5 a0 08 c3 a9 70 c2 bf 75 16 c2 81 30 53 c2 ab c5 be 1c c2 bd 77 c5 a0 c2 be c2 ad c3 b7 c3 8e c3 91 c2 a4 30 c2 a3 c3 8a c3 9f c3 a2 7e 21 c2 81 32 21 c3 9c 74 e2 80 94 c3 aa c3 93 6c 02 c2 b3 c3 8c 61 c3 ad e2 80 9d c3 8a c3 87 1a c2 b7 c3 85 47 6a c3 b9 22 2a 49 c3 9d 63 19 3e 75 64 5b c3 84 c3 8f c3 8f 42 c5 92 7b 0e e2 80 b0 c6 92 c2 aa 73 e2 80 93 c2 a3 07 c6 92 c3 87 c2 9d e2 80 a2 c3 a2 c3 88 30 c3 a4 20 c3 93 06 02 3c c2 b6 c3 bb 6f 65 c5 a0 c3 95 c3 a1 c3 a9 e2 80 9a e2 80 93 10 0c c3 af 73 c3 b7 c3 83 12 c3 86 e2 80 94 e2 80 98 c2 ae c3 a4 31 31 e2 80 a1 c2 be 0a 56 c2 9d 0e 3e c3 9b 20 2d 69 c3 ae 23 e2 80 a0 c3 86 3e e2 80 93 e2 80 a0 e2 80 9c 10 c2 b9 2d 3f e2 80 9e 02 c5 be 15 c3 82 15 c2 b9 34 c3 a1 30 4c 62 2b 1b c3 b0 12 c2 b3 c2 bf 1d 75 c2 81 c3 a1 6a c2 be 37 e2 82 ac c3 bc c2 9d c2 a8 c3 83 c3 ab 56 c3 ae c3 ac c2 b4 c2 90 6d c2 bd c3 80 06 c3 bd 55 5f c2 a7 c2 b9 c3 90 c2 a6 19 e2 80 a1 21 40 54 0e 0a cb 86 c3 ad 59 46 04 6a c2 9d 3d 71 c5 a0 c3 be c2 a0 c2 af c2 90 c3 8e c2 a3 57 c3 81 4d c3 bd 51 33 c3 82 c2 b2 72 c3 83 c3 ae e2 80 9a e2 80 93 05 44 7e 24 21 34 c3 90 e2 84 a2 41 0c 4b c2 b4 c3 89 c2 a1 c2 b4 2a c2 ad c2 bc c5 be 4a 03 5b c2 a4 c3 86 4d c3 80 10 c3 bd 02 c2 b6 c3 81 c2 a4 c3 9f 29 c3 b5 c3 ad c3 a8 41 c2 b3 c3 85 c3 ac c3 a4 2b 28 13 6c e2 82 ac c3 b5 c3 a8 2b c3 86 34 c3 b9 32 c3 9b 26 c3 90 c2 a2 e2 80 9e c3 91 55 c2 b8 c3 bd 28 c3 bf c2 b1 74 18 5f c2 8d 29 21 c3 a7 11 73 c3 a2 27 7a e2 80 b9 19 c3 bc e2 80 9a c3 bc c3 b0 cb 9c e2 80 b0 c3 8b 21 c3 89 c3 b5 63 54 25 c3 ad c3 a5 26 7d 58 e2 80 b0 c3 81 c3 a3 c2 b9 04 27 13 c3 81 c3 aa 29 37 c3 81 4d e2 80 9d 15 24 26 c3 ad 22 59 20 4b 7b c3 8a c3 a3 0e 15 1a 0a c2 b3 78 7e 33 48 10 03 32 25 c3 b2 33 56 43 3c 18 c3 9f c2 ac 79 c2 ab e2 80 a0 e2 80 9e 44 6c 2d 4c c3 a5 4d c2 b7 63 c2 b9 c3 91 11 c2 ac 01 41 04 3a 40 c3 91 c3 8b c3 80 36 c3 85
```

When I try to convert the hex values to ASCII, I get the content of the original file back.
Any suggestions how to convert the content of the .bin file to a readable hash table (e.g. csv)?

The .bin files are part of an old software package [All-Zero Hash Calculator](https://www.edenprime.com/tools/epAllZeroHashCalculator.htm)

Comment: The format of the file is likely proprietary and will require at least some reverse engineering and possibly a lot. When you say the contents didn't make sense to you I have to wonder what you expected to see. Also, if the tool only calculates hashes of zeros what is the file for?

Comment: The files properbly contain pre-calculated "intermediate hash'es" so the tool can deliver a results within 1 second on any length up to 2TB. So calculating a hash on any length would involve looking up the nearest pre-calculation, and then move forward from there.